# Download latest uploaded file from amazon s3 using boto3 in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have `few csv files inside` one of my `buckets on amazon s3.`

I need to `download the latest uploaded csv file.`

How to achieve this using `boto3 in python??`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

S3 doesn't have an API for listing files ordered by date
However, if you indeed have only a few, you can list the files in the bucket and order them by last modification time.

```
bucketList = s3Client.list_objects(Bucket=<MyBucket>) # notice this is up to 1000 files
orderedList = sorted(bucketList, key=lambda k: k.last_modified)
lastUpdatedKey = orderedList[-1]
object = s3Client.get_object(Bucket=<MyBucket>, Key=lastUpdatedKey )
```

Comment: Notice I've referenced answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969653/s3-boto-list-files-within-a-bucket-by-upload-time