# Is there a more performant way of sorting this array?

Tags: python, performance, sorting, amazon-s3, boto3

This script fetches last_modified attributes of every file in an S3 bucket then sorts them and downloads the latest file. However it already takes pretty long and I was wondering if there is a way to boost performance.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket(name='mytestbucket')
allobjects = bucket.objects.filter()

a=[]
for obj in allobjects:
  a.append(obj.last_modified)

a.sort()
b = a[-1]

for obj in allobjects:
  if obj.last_modified == b:
    c = obj.key

s3.Bucket('mytestbucket22').download_file(c, 'c:\latest.csv')
```

Comment: Maybe make it so alphabetical order is modification order if possible? That way, you can just use `.limit(1)`.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/7974123/707111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. There are two things here that can be optimized:

1. you do not need to `sort` if you want to obtain the `max`;
2. you do not have to search for the object once sorted.

You can simply use:

```
import boto3
from operator import attrgetter

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket(name='mytestbucket')
allobjects = bucket.objects.filter()

c = max(allobjects,key=attrgetter('last_modified')).key

s3.Bucket('mytestbucket22').download_file(c, r'c:\latest.csv')
```

By using `max` we will obtain the element in `allobjects` that is the largest according to the `key`. As `key` here, we use `attrgetter('last_modified')` that, for an element `x` will fetch `x.last_modified`.

Note that we **calculate the `max(..)` on `allobjects` itself**. Next we get the `key` of that object.

Sorting a list works in *O(n log n)* whereas calculating the maximum works oin *O(n)*, so this will definitely work faster. Furthermore the fact that we do not need to search for the element again, will have an impact as well. Finally it is more elegant: we simply state that we want to find the maximum object according to some `key`: it is more readable to a programmer.